# Displaying Foreign Key data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a BusinessID in both my staff and business table and I'm wanting to display the staff members for everyone in a particular business. The query below gives me this error.

```
ERROR: Could not able to execute SELECT * FROM business b inner join BusinessID b ON b.BusinessID = s.BusinessID WHERE b.BusinessID = 1. Not unique table/alias: 'b'
```

This is my foreign key file

```
<html>

<body>

<?php

include_once("connect.php");


$BusinessID = $_GET['BusinessID'];


$sql=   "SELECT *
        FROM business b
        inner join BusinessID b
        ON b.BusinessID = s.BusinessID
        WHERE b.BusinessID = $BusinessID"; 




if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Name</th>";
                echo "<th>BusinessID<th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $row['BusinessID'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        $result->free();
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $conn->error;
}

// Close connection
$conn->close();
?>


    </body>

</html>
```

Below is the fix

```
$sql=   "SELECT *
        FROM staff 
         WHERE BusinessID = $BusinessID";
```

Comment: What is the current output from this query?  What are your table definitions?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Where is "a BusinessID"?

Comment: I'm passing BusinessID from another file.

"href=\"foreignKey.php?BusinessID=$row[BusinessID]"

Comment: Why not just query select * from staff where s.BusinessID = that value? And please see my first comment. Eg "doesn't seem to do much" means nothing.

Comment: my apologises I've updated it to show what i've tried and i hope that is a bit better.

Comment: Just fixed it. Thanks for the help everyone and especially you phillipxy you pretty much fixed it with that suggestion. Sorry about not really explaining much.

Comment: Now that you have the form of your query, beware of SQL code injection. PS I just posted my comment as an answer (also addressing injection). PPS Keep working on clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a join statement

```
Select * 
From staff as S
Join business as B
on s.businessID=b.businessID
--Where clause <--- If you want to filter by anything.
```

Comment: The comma is a join, and the where (& your on) already is filtering.

Comment: It's still giving me my weird output.

Comment: What the output?

Answer (score 0):

You say you "have a BusinessID". If it were in $BusinessID, the form of query you want seems to be:

```
query select * from staff where s.BusinessID = $BusinessID
```

*However* be warned of *SQL code injection* as addressed at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/3404097) (See also the coincidental meta post from *today* [Should the answer be the simplest ever possible, even at the expense of quality/security?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345664/3404097)) The correct way to deal with this in  a PHP context is to query via prepared statements.